# Do the Borg ever focus on assimilating Data in particular?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg, star-trek-data

Do the Borg believe that Data is inferior to them somehow?

Data's technology is demonstrated to be somewhat compatible with (and perhaps superior than) the Borg in *The Best of Both Worlds*, and in *Descent Part 1*, Data shows that he is physically stronger than a Borg drone.

Certainly the Borg want to assimilate all of humanity, however they have shown favoritism (the Drone episode from voyager comes to mind as an example) when there is a particularly "juicy" target. Does Data not qualify as such? or is the entire enterprise at the same level of "juiciness" for the Borg?

Comment: guess you havn't seen first contact.

Comment: their assimilation works through nano probes that infest a biological creature, since data has no biological parts he is in essence immune to traditional assimilation, and his neural-net is far to complex for the borg to decipher/force assimilate him. it has to be a choice for data.

Comment: @Himarm - yep, I missed that movie - at the same time, how do they manage to assimilate the mobile emitter in the Drone episode then? that's a purely non-biological device.

Comment: thats simple technology not sentient AI

Comment: @Himarm: They assimilate ships and all sorts. I think it's fair to say that nanoprobes could do a decent number on Data.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit in the movie they specifically talk about how they wouldn't be able to do much to him, and like i said data is far more advanced then federation ships, and most of the other ships the borg have infiltrated.

Comment: @Himarm: Please quote said talk. I don't recall it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Lieutenant Commander Data: I am unlike any lifeform you have encountered before. The codes stored in my neural net cannot be forcibly removed." to me this sounds like they cannot get into his brain, aka assimilate him, they can mess with his outershell but his brain is safe and secure. the borg queen then says finding a weakness is only a mater of time, however instead of doing that she then starts her talks to persuade data to join willingly, im not saying after months or years could they not crack data, but he is essentially immune to the threat.

Comment: and would probably wipe his own mind before they could succeed if they ever managed to do this.

Comment: @Himarm: That was about the cryptography of the Enterprise's codes. Doesn't really say anything about assimilation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit assimilation grants all of the memories and knowledge of the individual, if they cant crack into data's brain to retrieve the codes, then they cant assimilate him, since assimilating him would provide them with the information they required.

Comment: @Himarm: You're making vast sweeping assumptions. One obvious counter-example to your claim is Unimatrix Zero. It is false logic to say "assimilation gives you access to all memories, so if there is one blocked memory, it will be biologically impossible to assimilate you". It's clearly not the case that the nanoprobes will refuse to take over cells/technology in your body after magically divining that, once they've assimilated you, the collective still won't be able to access one or two of your memories.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In the movie *First Contact* the queen actively attempts to assimilate/turn Data into a Borg, by giving him skin implants that allow him the real sensations of a biological being, thus tempting Data. The Borg are unable to assimilate Data as he is technically more advanced than they are mechanically, however Data can choose to join the Borg and he would then be able to assimilate into the hive, and gain biological components.

The queen says he would be like her equal in leading the Borg (if I remember correctly). Data actually considers it for a fraction of a second but decides he is content to become more human on his own.

[image: Data and the Borg Queen]

Comment: It's revealed in that film that the Borg Queen originally wanted to share leadership with Picard, but he refused and was turned into Locutus instead. I guess even Borg Queens get lonely sometimes. She should join eHarmony.

Comment: @JamesSheridan haha, i think its because she wanted to have an equal, someone to discuss and debate with about plans ect, with the collective she knew everything that the others knew, she never got to see opposing views, or tactics.

Comment: I'm sure she wanted all those things too. But mostly, it was the sex. Hell, I'd sleep with Picard, and I'm a heterosexual man.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the Queen doesn't have any lower bits, just a sexy looking spinal column.

Comment: Great image of Data and the Borg Queen.

Comment: Dat spinal column

Comment: Data does partially assimilate. In addition to the biological skin graphs, Data uses the Borg hive communication network to reach out to Picard while Picard is evacuating the Enterprise. But it's definitely clear that assimilating Data is a process, and one that the Borg cannot expedite like they can with biologicals.

Comment: Wait tho. In the second episode with Locutus, he looks at data and says something like "android. Inferior." Inferior because a cyborg has all the strengths of both or something along those lines. So that rather confuses the matter, does it not?

Answer (score 3):

I think the story of the Borg queen desiring a companion brings out the age old idea that if there is a shred of humanity in someone, they desire companionship.  This, I believe, was to inspire the hope that is included in the very idea of Star Trek, that things will get better.  With a Borg queen longing for companionship, there is the possibility of infiltration, wooing, and redirecting of the Borg.

Captain Kirk actually solved the Borg problem in the book "The Return".

Comment: Isn't he dead by the time the federation encounters them?

Comment: @Hal Pitiable things like that cannot stop the great Captain Kirk.  The book was co-written by Shatner, and spares no ego.

Answer (score 0):

The borg needed his command codes. Assimilation would not necessarily recover encrypted data and may even alter how data encrypts and decrypts by the usual Borg upgrade process.  "I understand that you have no interest in me, that your goal is access to the encryption codes for the enterprise computer!"
   He would also be upgraded, and possibly reprogrammed, which would likely alter how he encrypts and decrypts, and may actually make him more problematic as he would be a Borg upgraded Soong type android!
   This makes sense if then data is also encoded in a relativistic rather than absolute fashion, relating data to other data (see Marvin Minsky's frames theory).
   Locutus says, specifically, that Data will be obsolete in the new order.  However, technically, he does have brain scans of a great number of scientists and was stated in one episode to have improved one of his systems, so who knows what he would become!  I do not believe they cared, but we do.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the relevance of Minsky's theory of frames? As a non-expert, I have a bit of trouble understanding its meaning here.